# Работа с строковым типом данных

Tags: c#, строки

Помогите, пожалуйста с задачей:
Дана строка символов. Сформировать новую строку, в которую
включить все символы исходной строки, стоящие на четных местах.
При этом должен быть обратный порядок следования символов по отношения
к исходной строке.

Если что, вот код:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = listBox2.SelectedIndex;
    string str = (string)listBox2.Items[index];
    int len = str.Length;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < len)
        if (index % 2 == 0)
            listBox2.Items.Add(str[index]);
         i++;
}
```

Comment: Пример кода должен быть минимальным, вам правильно предложили вырезать половину кода - из очереди проверок.

Comment: В меню Visual Studio выберите пункт Edit > Advanced > Format Document (шорткат Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D). И осознайте, что `i++` находится _за_ циклом. Добавьте фигурные скобки циклу `while`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var g = "current string to reverse";

            var ch = g.Where((c, i) => i % 2 == 0);
            var result = String.Join("", ch.Reverse());
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadKey();
```

ну если вам по Forms то так

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       var g = "current string to reverse";

                var ch = g.Where((c, i) => i % 2 == 0);
                var result = String.Join("", ch.Reverse());
    }
```

Comment: А если под Windows Forms?

Comment: поправил по win forms

Comment: Лучше использовать `string.Concat` вместо `Join`, т. к. сепаратор не нужен.